# PHP PDO mssql error

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo

I was using mssql pdo for PHP 5.3.1, It was running without any problems, suddenly I have found, all my insert queries fails while running from php PDO, If I echo the query and run it in SQL server Management studio, It runs without any error. below is my echo query

```
INSERT INTO contactus(title, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES('Mr', 'Robin', 'Michael', 'robin@robin.com')
```

below is the error

```
Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 10007 [2] => Incorrect syntax near 'Mr'. [10007] (severity 5) [INSERT INTO contactus(title, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES('Mr] [3] => -1 [4] => 5 )
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue??

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: @JW웃 I have updated my question with error

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have set error mode, even I am getting same error message

Comment: What if you create a statement and bind parameters rather than hard coding the values? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Your error (which includes the array keys in the string) seems to imply that you are attempting to bind params by passing an array. You need to post the PHP code you used to bind these parameters rather than just echoing out the query.

Comment: Will he ever post the code ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290145/windows-update-pdo-sql-server-driver-issue#comment25069563_17290145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the issue, This is because of recent windows update on my machine and our windows server. After this update mssql pdo driver throws this error. I have downloaded sqlsrv20 driver from microsoft website and placed the file
    php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll inside php extension directory and added new extension in php.ini file like    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll and changed the pdo connectivity

```
$dbcon = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$conf->host;Database=$conf->db_name", $conf->db_user, $conf->db_pwd);
```

Note : for wamp server users needs to check php.ini in apache also and needs to add the extension in php.ini file under apache.